# Chrome Dev Tools - Can you undo changes in the console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

If you enter a command in Chrome Dev tools (which could be one big block of code) and hit enter, is there a way to "undo" changes made to the DOM? Or do you simply have to refresh the page?

Comment: just refresh the page - theres no undo.

Comment: Read the guide: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: I don't understand why the downvotes. "Just refresh" isn't good enough since it might take a few steps to get to the state you want to go back to, specially for single page apps. Undo changes would definitely be a helpful feature.

Comment: yvesmancera - it would be great to have this feature. Refreshing the page very often can be very time consuming, especially when there are slow-loading elements.

Comment: ctrl+z undo some changes.

Answer (score 12):

I too was looking for an answer to this question beyond "refresh the page"... Stumbled across this solution:

> 1. Enter Chrome dev tools (CMD + Shift + I on Mac)
> 2. Click the three dots aligned vertically to get the settings menu
> 3. Hover over "More Tools" then go to "Changes"
> 4. On the changes window you can see all the changes made during your current DOM editing session - to revert them all, simply click the
>      undo arrow in the bottom left...

**See the visual below**

[Reset all changes made in Chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Znm6l.jpg)

Comment: It will only undo the changes made in external css

Comment: This does not work for changes made to the actual DOM, like class changes or inline style changes.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what that code actually does. For example if you change something in the style (css) or structure (html), if you refresh it will show the original page. But if that code changes a cookie value, refreshing is not enough, or even closing the browser and opening again.